# Classification of space-filling (by identical copies) convex polyhedra in R^3

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, convex-polytopes, polyhedra

Is the classification of space-filling (by identical copies) convex polyhedra in R^3 is known ?

There are only 5 "parallelohedra" - filling by translation.
But if relax that property to identical (but not necessary by parallel translation),
there are more as
[Wikipedia suggests](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Honeycomb_(geometry)#Space-filling_polyhedra). But  it is not clear is the list described there is final or not.

To be precise I am asking about honeycombs filling the space by copies of single polyhedron,
not several of them, as it happens, for example in famous [Weaire–Phelan structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weaire%E2%80%93Phelan_structure).

Comment: I remember working, unsuccessfully, under John Conway on space-filling tetrahedra in 1975. Michael Goldberg, Three infinite families of tetrahedral space-fillers, Journal of Combinatorial Theory, Series A Volume 16, Issue 3, May 1974, Pages 348-354 https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0097316574900582 was probably state-of-the-art at the time.

Comment: See also Marjorie Senechal, Which Tetrahedra Fill Space? Mathematics Magazine Vol. 54, No. 5 (Nov., 1981), pp. 227-243. https://www.jstor.org/stable/2689983?seq=1

Comment: @GerryMyerson Thank you very much !